# Assigning an object to a variable with methods in catch block

Tags: java

When I try to compile my code I get error cannot find symbol for `.size()` and `.get(int)`.

If I move the for loop outside the catch block I get a cannot find symbol error for the 
currentUserDiary variable.

`getExisitingDiaries()` returns a `DiaryBook` so I thought this would work.

Just wondering if there is something wrong with assigning an Object to a variable this way or if theres something wrong with the rest of my code.

I have to use the catch block because the methods read from a text file.

```
AccountList aListOb = new AccountList();
try {
    aListOb.loadExistingDiaries(myAccountName);
    DiaryBook currentUserDiary = new DiaryBook();
    currentUserDiary = aListOb.getExistingDiaries(myAccountName);

    for (int i = 0; i < currentUserDiary.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(currentUserDiary.get(i));
    }

} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

these methods are in the AccountList class:

```
public void loadExistingDiaries(String name) throws IOException {
    for(int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (aList.contains(new Account(name, null))) {
            aList.get(i).loadExistingDiaries();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public DiaryBook getExistingDiaries(String name) throws IOException {
    DiaryBook d = new DiaryBook();
    for(int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (aList.contains(new Account(name, null))) {
            aList.get(i).loadExistingDiaries();
            d = aList.get(i).getDiaryBook();
            break;
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Does `DiaryBook` have these methods? It looks to me that you are trying to use `DiaryBook` as `List`, which may or may not be fine. Show `DiaryBook` or we can't help.

Comment: where is the difference between aListOb.loadExistingDiaries(myAccountName); and aListOb.getExistingDiaries(myAccountName);??

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `new DiaryBook()` if you're just going to replace the value with something else in the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a variable declared inside a try block is the try block itself, Trying to access it from outside will cause a compilation error, since that variable is not visible.

If you want to use that variable outside the try you need to declare it outside as well.

```
DiaryBook currentUserDiary = null;

try {
    aListOb.loadExistingDiaries(myAccountName);
    currentUserDiary = aListOb.getExistingDiaries(myAccountName);

    for (int i = 0; i < currentUserDiary.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(currentUserDiary.get(i));
    }

} catch (IOException e) {

}

if(currentUserDiary != null){
    //Do your business
}
```

Comment: thanks! my main problem was actually that I needed a method to get the ArrayList out of the DiaryBook (stupid mistake!), but this helped me understand the errors I got immediately after I worked that out.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt share the code of DiaryBook. So can't tell if get() and size() are actually declared.

1. Make sure get() and size() are declared in DiaryBook and are visible(public accessor).
2. Type cast it to DiaryBook when getting from a Generic List.

And, as suggested by Guillermo Merino, declare the variable outside the try catch block to be able to use it.